# How to subtract 3D matrix in matlab?

Tags: matrices, matlab

What is the correct way to subtract  A ([a,b,c]=size (A)) from  matrix B ([a,b,c]=size (B)) over the second dimension

something like:  minus (A,B,2)?

Thanks in advance,
karlo

p.s, probably it has a simple solution and i really confused! your help is very much appreciated

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by subtracting "over the second dimension"? How is that different than just doing B-A?

Comment: in a 2D matrix,C= A-B means subtracting every element 
E.G,. C(2,1)= A(2,1)-B(2,1), or , C(3,4)=A(3,4)-B(3,4), ......                                         But in a 3D, we apply A-B i am not sure what does the output mean?!  some function or trick like mean(A,2)

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are 3D arrays of numbers, and $C = A - B$, then $C_{i,j,k} = A_{i,j,k} - B_{i,j,k}$.  Is that not the operation that you want to perform?